# Slick2d Java reversing the moving direction of an object

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm working on this game using Java and slick2d library and I'm supposed to reverse the direction of some moving vehicles (eg:bikes) when they reach a certain x-coordinate. 
Logic seems simple enough, yet some of them move right past the x-coordinate, while some reverses the direction. Confused as to why. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code in the update() method. getX() returns the x location from superclass as a float. BIKE_SPEED is a float, delta being the milliseconds passed since last frame.

```
@Override 
    public void update(Input input, int delta) {
        if ((int)getX() == 24 || (int)getX() == 1000) {
            moveRight = !moveRight;
        }

        move(BIKE_SPEED * delta * (moveRight ? 1 : -1), 0);
    }
```

Comment: Try `<= 24` and `>= 1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with slick2d, but in general, it's better to use `>=` or `<=` instead of `==` in cases like this. The object (bike) may "jump" right past the boundaries, without triggering your change of direction condition.

Comment: You also could check a head. I mean like: if(x + velocity > limit). This might be looking smoother depending on where the x of your gameobjects hitbox is.